# An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket in flask

Tags: python, flask

Hey I am trying to run a flask application on different port using

```
args = r'<path to application>\server.py'
    p = Popen(['python', args, server_ip, str(server_port)], creationflags=CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE)
```

from another flask application running on server the new flask application is starting but giving the error

```
[WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

can anyone please help me out?

I have already tried using different methords such as os.startfile(), subprocess.open() etc.

Comment: What is inside `args`, `server_ip` and `server_port`? Does running this outside of flask app is working ok?

Comment: yes its working fine